# How to update tableviewcell in realtime when the corresponding secondViewController changes

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, nstimer

I am creating a simple to-do app where you can create a task and when you tap on the tableviewcell it takes you to the secondVC(EditVC) where you can edit the task and also set reminder for it. When the reminder is set a bellicon appears in the respective tableviewcell.

Now I want the bellicon to be removed on tableviewcell when the reminder is up in realtime. Every task has a date/time with it which I compare with the current time. I am doing similar thing in editVC where I have a timer which gets fired for the respective time and updates a label "Time's up' in realtime.

I want similar functionality in the tableview as well. So for example in firstVC you have three to four tasks. Task B has a reminder set and there is a purple bell icon next to it. When the notification is triggered and the reminder time is up, the bell icon is removed from the correct cell in realtime.

I guess the only concept I am not able to grasp is how can I keep track of which task reminder got triggered and then how am I suppose to know which cell is to be updated.

Please help!

Code in the editVC for updating the label in realtime when the reminder time is up:
This is in `viewWillAppear`

```
guard let selectedDate = editnotes?.sSelectedDate else {
    print("No date selected")
    return
}
self.timesUpTimer = Timer(fireAt: selectedDate, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timesUpTimer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

This is the selector function:

```
@objc func updateTimeLabel()
{
    editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time's up"
    editnotes?.belliconcolor = .white
    reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
    print("Time is up ok")
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the task (or some unique task ID) that has the reminder as userInfo when creating the timer and then identify the correct row in the table view using that task in the #selector method.

Assuming you have class/struct Task for each row, I would attach the task instance for the current row, like

```
self.timesUpTimer = Timer(fireAt: selectedDate, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: ["task": task], repeats: false)
```

and then in the selector

```
@objc func updateTimeLabel(_ timer: Timer)
{
    editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time's up"
    editnotes?.belliconcolor = .white
    reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var task = userinfo["task"] as Task
    // do stuff with task object
}
```

Comment: Can you just give me a short code snippet for better understanding? Help is appreciated:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Just couple of questions: 
1. I set the date for a particular row in secondVC, do I have to send it to the firstVC where I create the timer. 
2. "task" is a uniqueID for each task? 
3. Do I have to make one timer for each task?
4. I do have a class of NSManagedObject that I am using with CoreData. Will it work with it?

Comment: 1. I assume so but it is not part of the question. 2. Task is something I made up as an example but it looks like it corresponds to the managed object you mention in question 4. 3. Not part of the question. 4. Yes.

Comment: Can you give me some more info on this. I have posted a new question please help me. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983661/how-to-create-array-of-timers-that-update-each-tableviewcell-when-they-are-invok