# How to create array of timers that update each tableviewcell when they are invoked?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

Over the last couple of days I have been trying to figure out how I can update a tableViewCell from TableView controller and it's giving me hard time. Here is where I have reached thus far:

**Creating a timer**

I set the time for the reminder in editVC(which you accessed by tapping on the tableViewCell). There you can set the time and the reminder is made. Every task has `sSelectedDate` which is the date set by the user.

This is what I think I should do next: Send this `sSelectedDate` to the firstViewController(where the tableView resides) and use this date to create a timer in the firstVC.

**Question:** What is the correct way of sending the particular date from the task to firstVC?

```
timesUpTimer = Timer(fireAt: selectedDate, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabel), userInfo: ["taskID": EditNotes], repeats: false)
```

**UserInfo Dilemma**

The "taskID" I am sending can be a uniqueTaskID I can generate with each task when a reminder is created. `EditNotes` is the `class` of `NSManagedObject` for CoreData.

**Question**: What's the correct way of sending the uniqueTaskID to the firstViewController?

**Selector Method**

```
@objc func updateTimeLabel(_ timer: Timer)
{

    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    var task = userinfo["taskID"] as EditNotes
    task.belliconcolor = .white 
    // do stuff with task object

}
```

Since I am changing the coreData here I hope FetchedResultsController method is triggered and the tableView is updated.

This is the method invoked when a timer is up.

**Question:** Should I only rely on FRC or should I actually update the corresponding row in tableview? If yes then how?

**Should I create Array for timers**

This timer I create in the firstVC is for just one task? Do I have to create an array of timers and save it in coreData also?

**Question:** How to do it?

**TLDR:**
How to create timers/array of timers for every element/task of the tableview that when invoked updates the corresponding row in the tableview?

Comment: __Q1:__ why do you need timer rather then performing a selector for such task? __Q2:__ how could you be sure the cell is still visible on the screen for the data when the timer is triggered? __Q3:__ why not focus on managing the updates on _model_ and triggering an update on _view_ when a new data is visible instead (through notifications maybe)?

Comment: I am using a timer so that it could be triggered at the time set by the user for the task. the timer will be deleted when the row is deleted?. Can you suggest some code or any example that I can use because I am seriously stuck at the issue for the last 48 hours!

Comment: you need to start triggering the update-procedure down from your _model_ (not from your _view_); so the updating the _model_ can trigger an (uncoupled) update on _view_ because there is no guarantee the _view_ is still visible when the update happens on the _model_ – basically that is the concept I would go for, if I were you.

Comment: I completely get this concept. So basically when I set a reminder for the task and it adds a sSelectedDate in the coreData, then I can send a notification to the firstVC and it can do the update. How am I supposed to keep track of which row to be updated or which 'indexPath' got updated?

Comment: I'm not sure which architecture you are using in your project, so there are various ways to do so; like __e.g.__ you can check the pointer of _BO_ on your _controller_ for whether you have an active _view_ for it; or __e.g.__ your _model_ can just post a notification what your active _view_ (for the same _BO_) listens and updates the view... there are various ways, but these opinion-based ideas, the 'proper' solution depends on what kinda architecture you are using in your project like I mentioned at the beginning :)